# C++ Code translation to Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am trying to convert a C++ opencv script to Java but there is this little line I keep running into: `Mat.data[x]`. I checked the Java version and the closest method I could find was `Mat.dataAddr()`. Look at the way its been used in the code below:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
{ // average row by row
    row = src.row(i);
    mean = 0;
    for (j = 0 ; j < row.cols ; j++)
    {
        // here is the method 
        mean + = row.data[j];
    }
    mean /= row.cols;
    dist.data[i] = mean;
}
```

It seems like they are trying to access the index of the Matrix but what `column` and `row` it is they are trying to access?

Comment: Why don't you just multiply `src` by a `cols x 1` matrix filled with `1.0 / cols`?

Comment: I mean: why bother accessing the individual elements to calculate the average, why not do it as a matrix multiplication?

Comment: @AndyTurner I just need the java translation of `row.data[j]`

Comment: @ChromeLanta *I just need the java translation of row.data[j]* -- What is the glaring difference between what that line looks like (and does) in Java as opposed to C++?  I don't see any.  So you're saying you would be stumped if you saw this in a Java program: `row.data[j]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet is trying to compute an average for each row of all the elements in that row. The input 2-D matrix is `src`, the output 1-D array is `dist`.

So for each row (using index variable `i`), it gets the entire row into a variable named, appropriately, `row`.

```
row = src.row(i);
```

After that, it iterates over the values in that row using variable `j` as the index, adding each value to the variable `mean`.

```
    mean + = row.data[j];
```

And there's the line you mentioned. All that does is reference the j-th element of an array. In this case, the array is a 1-D array of values for the row `i`. So it's row `i` and column `j`, and `row.data[j]` just gets the value of that element.

@Andy Turner's comment (multiply `src` by a `cols` x 1 matrix filled with 1.0 / `cols`) is the most straightforward way to compute the mean, but it requires one to understand a bit of linear algebra (which one should, if one is writing matrix manipulation code).

Comment: @Erick G. Hagstrom thanks alot, I guess I have to re - visit my `Linear Algebra`

Comment: You can also use [reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce), with parameters `dim=1` and `rtype = CV_REDUCE_AVG`. Well, whatever this is called in the OpenCV Java wrapper.